# update instead of show being called in REST rails form submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a form that a user submits. The form is for a user.  I have the following in my routes.rb file:

```
 resources :users, :except => [:new]

  root :to => 'pages#home'
  match '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact'
  match '/about',   :to => 'pages#about'
  match '/help',    :to => 'pages#help'
```

In the users_controller.rb:

```
  def create
    @title = "Home"
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to user_path(@user), :flash => {:success => "Your friend's details have been saved.The surprise has begin"} }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render :template => 'pages/home'}
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

This form is being submitted with a regular POST request and not Ajax.

I want to know why the Update template is being requested after the form is successfully submitted instead of the Show.

The output from rake routes is as follows:

```
    users GET    /users(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
          POST   /users(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
     user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
          PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
          DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
     root        /(.:format)               {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"home"}
  contact        /contact(.:format)        {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"contact"}
    about        /about(.:format)          {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"about"}
     help        /help(.:format)           {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"help"}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found the problem. I was not replacing the form but rendering the same form inside the form tags on the same page.  For some reason rails then put the path as edit_user_path so it was thinking to post or put to an update.  I fixed the ajax so the form is replaced by the new form and it all works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the code for the controller and view of this form?  Is there an existing user object when you generate the form or do you create a new user object (ie. @user = User.new in your controller)?  If there is an existing user then the form will submit to update.

Answer (score 0):

Your route and controller code look good, i.e. it should be sending you to the show method in your users_controller.  I'd put some debbugging code in there, i.e. `logger.debug("Inside Show")` to see if the show method was being called.

You could also include the output of `rake routes` in your edited question, it might be informative to show where the user_path helper is going to send the redirect.

ian.